# Code change vb.net to c#

Tags: c#, vb.net

I have no idea where to ask a question like this, so probably should say sorry right away.

```vb
 Private Function RCON_Command(ByVal Command As String, ByVal ServerData As Integer) As Byte()
 Dim Packet As Byte() = New Byte(CByte((13 + Command.Length))) {}
 Packet(0) = Command.Length + 9       'Packet Size (Integer)
 Packet(4) = 0                        'Request Id (Integer)
 Packet(8) = ServerData               'SERVERDATA_EXECCOMMAND / SERVERDATA_AUTH (Integer)
 For X As Integer = 0 To Command.Length - 1
     Packet(12 + X) = System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetBytes(Command(X))(0)
 Next
 Return Packet
End Function
```

Can someone tell me how should this code look like in c#? Tried my self but always getting error `Cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'byte'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)`
Tried to cast, then getting error about no need to cast

My code:

```
        private byte[] RCON_Command(string command, int serverdata)
    {
        byte[] packet = new byte[command.Length + 13];
        packet[0] = command.Length + 9;
        packet[4] = 0;
        packet[8] = serverdata;

        for (int i = 0; i < command.Length; i++)
        {
            packet[12 + i] = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(command[i])[0];
        }
        return packet;
    }
```

error is in packet[0] and packet [8] line

Comment: "_... Tried my self but always getting error..._" -- Post what you tried.

Comment: Can you post your effort?  It seems like it should be an easy fix and we can show you where you went wrong instead of someone just doing it for you.

Comment: Command.Length and serverdata are ints (32bit). You're putting them into bytes (8bit). You need an explicit cast because you're going to lose 24 bits. The compiler wants you to confirm you want to do that by casting.

Answer (score 1):

Just add the explicit casts.  You might want to make sure that it's safe to down cast from a 32-bit value type to an 8-bit type.

```
packet[0] = (byte)(command.Length + 9);
...
packet[8] = (byte)serverdata;
```

**EDIT:**

TheEvilPenguin is also right that you will have a problem with your call to `GetBytes()`.

This is how I would fix it to make sure I don't change the meaning of the existing VB.NET code:

```
packet[12 + i] = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(new char[] {command[i]})[0];
```

And also, one more detail:

When you declare an array in VB.NET, you define the maximum array index. In C#, the number in the array declaration represents the number of elements in the array.  This means that in the translation from VB.NET to C#, to keep equivalent behavior, you need to add `+ 1` to the number in the array declaration:

```
byte[] packet = new byte[command.Length + 13 + 1]; // or + 14 if you want
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to cast the two items to byte before assigning them.  Another option I've done below is to change the method to accept `serverdata` as a `byte` instead of `int` - there's no point in taking the extra bytes only to throw them away.

Another problem is in the `for` loop - the indexer of `string` returns a char, which `UTF8.GetBytes()` can't accept.  I think my translation should work, but you'll need to test it.

```
private byte[] RCON_Command(string command, byte serverdata)
{
    byte[] packet = new byte[command.Length + 13];
    packet[0] = (byte)(command.Length + 9);
    packet[4] = 0;
    packet[8] = serverdata;

    for (int i = 0; i < command.Length; i++)
    {
        packet[12 + i] = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(command)[i];
    }
    return packet;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you go. The Terik converter was no use - that code wouldn't compile.
This code runs...

```
private byte[] RCON_Command(string Command, int ServerData)
{
    byte[] commandBytes = System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetBytes(Command);

    byte[] Packet = new byte[13 + commandBytes.Length + 1];
    for (int i = 0; i < Packet.Length; i++)
    {
        Packet[i] = (byte)0;
    }

    int index = 0;

    //Packet Size (Integer)
    byte[] bytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(Command.Length + 9);
    foreach (var byt in bytes)
    {
        Packet[index++] = byt;
    }

    //Request Id (Integer)
    bytes = BitConverter.GetBytes((int)0);
    foreach (var byt in bytes)
    {
        Packet[index++] = byt;
    }

    //SERVERDATA_EXECCOMMAND / SERVERDATA_AUTH (Integer)
    bytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(ServerData);
    foreach (var byt in bytes)
    {
        Packet[index++] = byt;
    }

    foreach (var byt in commandBytes)
    {
        Packet[index++] = byt;
    }

    return Packet;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the need for casting, you need to be aware that C# uses array sizes when creating the array, not the upper bound that VB uses - so you need "14 + Command.Length":

```
private byte[] RCON_Command(string Command, int ServerData)
{
    byte[] Packet = new byte[Convert.ToByte(14 + Command.Length];
    Packet[0] = Convert.ToByte(Command.Length + 9); //Packet Size (Integer)
    Packet[4] = 0; //Request Id (Integer)
    Packet[8] = Convert.ToByte(ServerData); //SERVERDATA_EXECCOMMAND / SERVERDATA_AUTH (Integer)
    for (int X = 0; X < Command.Length; X++)
    {
        Packet[12 + X] = System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetBytes(Command[X])[0];
    }
    return Packet;
}
```